# Jquery Flexslider in flexslider

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I have a problem with flexslider. I want create a flexslider inside another flexslider. tried to fix it so, but it does not work properly.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main-slider" class="flexslider" style="background-color: #000">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <div id="sec-slider" class="flexslider" style="background-color: #fff; height: 250px;">
                <ul class="slides">
                    <li><img src="img/slide-2.jpg" /></li>
                    <li><img src="img/slide-3.jpg" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><img src="img/slide-2.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/slide-3.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#main-slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    slideshowSpeed: 7000,
    prevText: "<i class='icon-chevron-left'></i>",
    nextText: "<i class='icon-chevron-right'></i>",
    controlsContainer: "#main-con"
});

$('#sec-slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    slideshowSpeed: 3000,  
    prevText: "<i class='icon-chevron-left'></i>",
    nextText: "<i class='icon-chevron-right'></i>"
});
```

Do you have any solutions?

Comment: I fixed the formatting on your code - makes it **much** easier for people to help you with it.  If you were able to put together a test case (with jsfiddle for example) that would even be better.

Comment: on a side note, stop using the `<i>` tag.  Its been deprecated for quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

Try delaying the loading time of the secondary slider using the before property as follows :

```
$(window).load(function () {

     $('#main').flexslider({
         animation: "slide",
         slideshowSpeed: 7000,
         controlsContainer: ".flex-container",
     });

     $('#sec-slider').flexslider({
         animation: "slide",
         slideshowSpeed: 3000,
         prevText: "<i class='icon-chevron-left'></i>",
         nextText: "<i class='icon-chevron-right'></i>"
         before: function (slider) {
             // delay loading this slider
             $('.slide').find('.li').delay(800);
         }
     });
 });
```